# Was Krishna a non-vegetarian?

Tags: krishna, puranas, non-vegetarian

We know Sri Krishna was a Kshatriya. Besides He had weapons with Him which were used to hunt animals.

Can we hence categorically state that he was a non-vegetarian? If so, why do we offer vegetarian food to Him at home (like butter and seedai)? Do we know anything about His favourite non-veg item from Puranas?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  There's already a question on the site about whether Rama was a non-vegetarian, so if you want to focus your question on just Krishna, then I'm happy to reopen it.

Comment: the reason for butter is because of the various leelas of Lord Sri Krishna where he used to eat butter from the different houses. I guess in bhagavata his various leelas and fondness of butter are depicted, which we humans have revered. As for seedai and such, I would guess that those delicacies are unique to different regions in India. Different regions celebrate differently by preparing different delicacies. For example, in one of the ISKCON temple where I went, I haven't seen seedais during janmashtami. All the best

Comment: So what is the answer over here? Did Krishna ate meat?

Comment: @user3750229 He must have, being a Khsatriya, although I believe there is no actual reference to confirm one way or other which is why this question remains unanswered.

Comment: In Geeta Krishna says..'Patram pushpam phalam toyam....'.which means: If 1 offers fruit,leaf,flower or water with Love I accept it. If he ate meat He would have mentioned it.Its not that every Kshatriy ate meat. Also as long as I know;there is no such references that he ate meat in scriptures.

Comment: you have 2 question whether he ate meat and why we offer butter etc, and both are not related to each other, even if he ate meat, butter was his favorite and he used to steal butter according to bhagwath , so people offer him what he likes.

and with time of course many places in India have stopped serving non veg food to temples which was common earlier.

Answer (score 8):

In Srimad Bhagavad Gita, Shri Krishna has specifically told what exact food He accept.

> पत्रम पुष्पम फलम तोयम यो मे भक्त्या प्रच्छति।
>
> तदहम भक्तत्युपहृतमश्नामि प्रयतात्मन:।। ([9.26](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-9-26/))
>
> If one offers Me with love and devotion
>
> a leaf, a flower, fruit or water, I will accept it.

That means he must be a vegetarian.

Comment: Tip: When you use blockquotes, you should provide a link to the source.

Comment: He is not talking about the food he ate. He is talking about offerings from devotees. That is not the food he ate. Does that mean he ate flowers, leaves? From the same logic you have used, he didn't drink milk? Then why didn't he mention it in BG?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma yep! Though I'm a practicing Krishna devotee myself, I've always felt commentators and satsang-givers (esp from a particular, well-known institution) use the above verse with quite a bit of intellectual-dishonesty to 'prove' Krishna was a vegetarian. 

My own faith says, He was a vegetarian, and even if He were not, I'd still remain His vegetarian devotee, BUT the verse above is SO NOT a proof of His being vegetarian.

Answer (score 2):

Lord Krishna did not eat meat- he promoted sattvic food in gita

> आयु:सत्वबलारोग्यसुखप्रीतिविवर्धना: | रस्या: स्निग्धा: स्थिरा हृद्या
>   आहारा: सात्विकप्रिया: || 8||
>
> āyuḥ-sattva-balārogya-sukha-prīti-vivardhanāḥ rasyāḥ snigdhāḥ sthirā
>   hṛidyā āhārāḥ sāttvika-priyāḥ
>
> āyuḥ sattva—which promote
>   longevity; bala—strength; ārogya—health; sukha—happiness; prīti—satisfaction; vivardhanāḥ—increase; rasyāḥ—juicy; snigdhāḥ—succulent; sthirāḥ—nourishing; hṛidyāḥ—pleasing
>   to the heart; āhārāḥ—food; sāttvika-priyāḥ—dear to those in the mode
>   of goodness
>
> Translation
>
> BG 17.8: Persons in the mode of goodness prefer foods that promote the
>   life span, and increase virtue, strength, health, happiness, and
>   satisfaction. Such foods are juicy, succulent, nourishing, and
>   naturally tasteful.

Also its a wrong interpretation that Lord Krishna ate meat because he was kshatriya, he grew up in cow herder family, most cow herder families in North India are primarily vegeterian, neither Mahabharata or bhagvatam mention anything about Krishna pataking in meat,

I can't even believe that rama ate meat too, the references to meat in ramayana are very few and almost all of them are indirect references nowhere it is mentioned that he ate meat explicitly.

Lord Vishnu represent sattva, one can't fathom that he can take part in meat.

Comment: "I can't even believe that rama ate meat too.." believes apart, the mention of rama ate meat , in Ramayana is not indirect unless you are following commentary of BG.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, obviously he ate, because kshatriyas of that time period ate meat and were allowed to hunt and eat all edible animals. It is mentioned in Bibek Debroy's Mahabharata that Krishna and Arjuna used to hunt in the forests near Indraprastha.  That's true. There's no fault of them. Its their accordance to dharma and cooperate with it. Yudhisthira also ate deer in the dwaitavana and is also mentioned and so they moved to the kamyaka woods.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE.You should cite sources to back your answer.

Comment: Bibek debroy is a director of some commercial serials and what he know about Krishna? Which purana has substantiated?

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan See [Bibek Debroy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibek_Debroy#Indology_and_others). I think he knows more about Mahabharata than you and me :P

Comment: he is not  a kshatriya, he is a yadava . Those days it is normal to eat non vegetarian foods. almost all the people including brahman ate non vegan foods , for those who require source kindly read mahabharatha by k.m.ganguly or one by manmadanath dutta. both are authentic and  translation of original.

Comment: @sv---Probably more than you  do not compare me at all  because your critics say I know nothing. Am happy to share the knowledge whatever I possess.

Comment: @sansknwoledge, provide link or source of your speculation..

Comment: @sansknwoledge Yadava means who is a descendant of king Yadu. Yadu is a king. He was a Kshatriya. Yadava was the name of a Kshatriya dynasty.

Answer (score 1):

[**harivamsa-viSNuparva-ch18 :**](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_017.html)

> *vishasyantAM cha pashavo **bhojyA ye mahiShAdayaH** | pravartyatAM cha yaj~no.ayaM sarvagopasusaMkulaH ||2-17-15*
>
> *Let us sacrifice the animals such as **buffalos to be eaten**. Let this sacrifice be conducted with all gopa-s.*