# Were Pandavas non-vegetarians?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, pandavas, non-vegetarian

We know that the Pandavas were Kshatriyas. Were they consuming non-vegetarian food?

Comment: I think yes. When they were in exile period or hiding in jungle after Lakshyagraha incident, there were some verses indicating that Yudisthir was missing some animals flesh. It could be during their stay with Hidimba also that they ate flesh.

Comment: @AshokKumar Yeah, you're right.  See my answer.

Comment: There's already a question re: Krishna: [Was Krishna a non-vegetarian?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7662/2995)...so you should edit the question and remove the part about Krishna.

Comment: @sv. See now you make sense.

Comment: Yes they did. Pandavas where kshyatriyas, they where allowed to hunt and eat it. During the war of Mahabharata many hunters where hired so that bhima would get all the meat possible. Earlier there was also the tradition of Bali. The meat was used as prasad.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Yes, the Pandavas did eat meat.**  In [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03256.htm) of the Vana Parva of the Mahabharata, Yudishthira tells his brothers that they should leave the Dwaita forest because they've been eating all the deer there, so out of compassion for the deer they move to the Kamyaka woods:

> Once on a time, as Yudhishthira lay down at night in the Dwaita woods, some deer, with accents choked in tears, presented themselves before him in his dreams. To them standing with joined hands, their bodies trembling all over that foremost of monarchs said, 'Tell me what ye wish to say. Who are ye? And what do ye desire?' Thus accosted by Kunti's son--the illustrious Pandava, those deer, the remnant of those that had been slaughtered, replied unto him, saying, 'We are, O Bharata, those deer that are still alive after them that had been slaughtered. We shall be exterminated totally. Therefore, do thou change thy residence. O mighty king, all thy brothers are heroes, conversant with weapons; they have thinned the ranks of the rangers of the forest. We few--the remnants,--O mighty-minded one, remain like seed. By thy favour, O king of kings, let us increase.' Seeing these deer, which remained like seed after the rest had been destroyed trembling and afflicted with fear, Yudhishthira the just was greatly affected with grief. And the king, intent on the welfare of all creatures, said unto them, 'So be it. I shall act as ye have said.' Awaking after such a vision, that excellent king, moved by pity towards the deer, thus spake unto his brothers assembled there, 'Those deer that are alive after them that have been slaughtered, accosted me at night, after I had awakened, saying, 'We remain like the cues of our lines. Blest be thou! Do thou have compassion on us.' And they have spoken truly. We ought to feel pity for the dwellers of the forest. **We have been feeding on them for a year together and eight months.** Let us, therefore, again (repair) to the romantic Kamyakas, that best of forests abounding in wild animals, situated at the head of the desert, near lake Trinavindu. And there let us pleasantly pass the rest of our time.'

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Would the Pandavas be accumulating bad karma if they killed deer?

Comment: @user3547 Thanks!  No, Kshatriyas are permitted to hunt and eat animals.  But if the Pandavas had decided to not eat meat, they would accumulated good karma; the Manu Smriti says abstaining from meat gives you as much Punya as performing 100 Ashwamedha Yagnas.  Plus it's compassionate to animals (which was Yudishthira's motive in leaving the forest), and vegetarian food gives you better gunas which can make you a better person.  So there are many excellent reasons to be a vegetarian.

Comment: If eating meat is a sin then why did Buddha, incarnation of Vishnu, eat meat?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Eating meat isn't a sin for Kshariyas, I was just outlining various benefits that can be obtained by abstaining from meat.  In any case, we shouldn't judge things by the actions of Buddha, since Vishnu specifically incarnated as Buddha in order to deceive people.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria But we don't need to rely on the example of Buddha.  Rama eats meat in the Ramayana.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan He may have incarnated to deceive people but still those who follow him are able to attain Moksha so people may have got deceived but they are able to realize the highest truth.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, I don't think Buddhism leads to Moksha, but as we've discussed before we have a difference of opinion concerning our view of other religions.

Comment: OP also asks _Was Krishna a Non-Vegetarian too?_...is there a mention in Mahabharata for Krishna as well? There's already a separate question for that though: [Was Krishna a non-vegetarian?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7662/2995)...so maybe we can edit this question and remove the part about the Krishna.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Kalki kills Buddhists at the end of Kaliyuga ( not sure some or all: there may be only few Buddhists at the end of Kali Yuga) and grants them all Moksha. So the mistakes done by Buddha will be rectified by Kalki.

Comment: @sv. OK, I edited it.

Comment: During those time the first three varnas including Kshtriyas wore the Yajñopavita. If I'm not wrong, those who wear the sacred thread are prohibited from consuming meat?

Comment: @Naveen No, there's no general prohibition on those wearing the sacred thread eating meat.  There is a prohibition on wearers of the sacred thread eating the meat of five-nailed animals, though: see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8687/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan do you have some article about Vishnu incarnating as Buddha to deceive people?

Comment: @aitchnyu Yes, see this chapter of the Vishnu Purana: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp092.htm

Answer (score 0):

In India actually meat was prohibited for a civilized person, here uncivilized means people who does not belong to the society, mostly who resides in forests (tribes). you can find following lines on Wikipedia about it:

> The fiend who smears himself with flesh of cattle, with flesh of
>   horses and of human bodies,
>   Who steals the milch-cow's milk away, O Agni,—tear off the heads of such with fiery fury.
>
> The cow gives milk each year, O Man-regarder let not the Yātudhāna ever taste it.
>
> If one would glut him with the biesting, Agni, pierce with thy flame his vitals as he meets thee.
>
> Let the fiends drink the poison of the cattle; may Aditi cast off the evildoers.
>
> May the God Savitar give them up to ruin, and be their share of plants and herbs denied them.
>
> Agni, from days of old thou slayest demons never shall Rākṣasas in fight o’ercome thee.
>
> Burn up the foolish ones, the flesh-devourers let none of them escape thine heavenly arrow.

— Rig Veda (10.87.16-19)

That means no one was allowed to eat meat and its kind of a sin. Surely Mahabharata time period is much before that so i don't think Pandavas ever eaten meat or something, and during there vanvaas they live like Brahmins so there is no question of meat there. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Brahmin_diet) is the link from wikipedia.

Comment: -1: Your quote from Rig Veda seems to be about Rakshasas (Rākṣasas), flesh-devourers. How does it apply to Pandavas and Krishna and how it does answer OP's question? Also, look at [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7097/2995) to [Was Lord Rama a non-vegetarian?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2002/2995)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define a "non-vegetarian".

If you define non-vegetarian as a person who eats ***captive-bred meat*** **(today’s scenario)**, then answer is **No**. ***pAndavas were not non-vegetarian because they did not eat this kind of meat***. The reason is because as per mahAbhArata anushasanaparva CXV ***captive-bred meat is sinful*** for all dvijas (brahman, kshatriya and vaishya):

> *He who permits (the slaughter of an animal), he who cuts it up, he who kills it, he who ****buys or sells (meat)****, he who cooks it, he who serves it up, and he who eats it, (must all be considered as) the slayers (of the animal).*
>
> *One should never eat, O chief of Bharata's race, like a Rakshasa, any meat that has been obtained by ****means not sanctioned by the ordinance****.*

One source of meat which was sanctioned by ordinance for practicing-kshatriyas was that obtained by hunting of wild animals i.e. ***venison-game*** as mentioned in anushasana parva Chapter CXVI of mahAbhArata:

> *Listen to me as I tell thee what the ordinance is that has been laid down for the Kshatriyas. They do not incur any fault by eating flesh that has been acquired by expenditure of prowess. All deer of the wilderness were dedicated to the deities and the Pitris in days of old, O king, by Agastya. Hence, the hunting of deer is not censured. ****There can be no hunting without risk of one's own life. There is equality of risk between the slayer and the slain. Either the animal is killed or it kills the hunter****. Hence, O Bharata, even royal sages betake themselves to the practice of hunting. By such conduct they do not become stained with sin. Indeed, the practice is not regarded as sinful.*

pAndavas consumed ***venison-game*** which is fundamentally different from modern day ***captive-bred meat*** as seen in mahAbhArata vana parva L :

> *"Those bulls among men, collecting the produce of the wilderness and ****hunting the deer**** with pure arrows,*
> *And ****hunting with arrows Rurus and the black deer and other kinds of clean animals of the wilderness****,*
> *And the king himself wending towards the east, and Bhima, towards the south, and the twins, towards the west and the north, daily ****hunted with bow in hand the deer of the forest, for the sake of venison****.*

The diet of pAndavas thus comprised of ***(veg + venison/game)*** as opposed to diet of modern day non-vegetarians which comprises of ***(veg + captive-bred meat)***.

***pAndavas in today's world would thus be vegetarian due to prohibitions on hunting.***