# Are there any references about Krishna eating meat?

Tags: scripture, krishna, non-vegetarian

In Mahabharata or any other scripture, are there any references which explicitly mention Lord Krishna eating meat like [those](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9301/were-pandavas-non-vegetarians) of Pandavas? 
As I did not find any reference in the other thread I have made a new thread for this.

Comment: in that thread no one has quoted any reference about eating .

Comment: Edit to make the question active or ask for references by editing it.